# Макрос codelobster или хоткей

Tags: php

Существует редактор кода codelobster. Нужно, чтобы по нажатию клавиши писался целый блок кода. Ищу второй день, не могу найти подобное. Или хотя бы меню готовых сниппетов, чтобы просто выбирать сохраненные куски кода. Подскажите есть ли вообще такое в данном редакторе?

Например:
Нажал CTRL+D - пишется строка - echo "hello world";

Comment: `php` не умеет работать с эмуляцией клавиш, этим занимается сам браузер то есть `javascript`.

Answer (score 2):

Инструменты->Настройки->Сниппеты->PHP->Создать. Например, создаёте такой шаблон в сниппетах `echo '<pre>'; var_dump(@); echo '</pre>';` и называете его `vd` -- и тогда при наборе в php-файле символов `vd` будет выведено имя сниппета в выпадающем списке. Вам останется кликнуть по нему, и весь блок кода запишется в ту область файла, где в этот момент стоит курсор. Обратите внимание -- знак `@` в коде сниппета указывает на положение курсора после вставки сниппета в файл с кодом.